# Remove path until slash when typing in terminal

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, shell, zsh

For instance, when I type a path in terminal

```
cd project/example/one
```

I can press `Ctrl+W` and remove the entire "word" `project/example/one`.
Sometimes it's not very useful.

Are there any shortcuts for removing only `one` word to make like following?

```
cd project/example/
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In shells with [GNU readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html#SEC5) you could combine the `backward-word` (*Move backward a word*, `Meta-b`) and `kill-line` (*Kill the text from the current cursor position to the end of the line*, `Ctrl-K`) commands.

There's also `backward-kill-word`, by default on `Meta-Backspace`.

To get commands in `zsh` to use the same word boundaries (it doesn't use GNU readline), I had to set `select-word-style bash`.